# Dataproc returning StatusRuntimeException cluster not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, data-processing

I am sending request to an API that is using gcloud Dataproc for reindexing. I am sending a request that is giving me response

**io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Not found: Cluster projects/go-dev-central/regions/us-central1/clusters/cluster-156c**

**Pretty new to gcloud don't know where i should be looking into. Can it be a regional/zone issue.**

```
Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.dataproc.v1.JobControllerClient.submitJob(JobControllerClient.java:210)
        at com.google.cloud.dataproc.v1.JobControllerClient.submitJob(JobControllerClient.java:183)
        at com.carecloud.edison.commons.providers.gcp.GoogleDataProcProvider.$anonfun$submitDataProcJob$1(GoogleDataProcProvider.scala:59)
        at com.carecloud.edison.commons.providers.gcp.GoogleDataProcProvider.withJobControllerClientSync(GoogleDataProcProvider.scala:39)
        at com.carecloud.edison.commons.providers.gcp.GoogleDataProcProvider.$anonfun$withJobControllerClient$1(GoogleDataProcProvider.scala:27)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:658)
        at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Not found: Cluster projects/go-dev-central/regions/us-central1/clusters/cluster-156c
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
2020-08-31 04:33:49,568 [ERROR] c.ReindexController - General Service Error: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Not found: Cluster projects/go-dev-central/regions/us-central1/clusters/cluster-156c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you used the separate "global" multiregion to create the cluster, even if you placed it in a GCE zone within us-central1, while you've configured your code to use the "us-central1" regional Dataproc universe.

See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints for more details on the difference. The high level is that "global" is an independent Dataproc universe, just like each of the different regional universes like "us-central1", "europe-west1", etc; they are all isolated from each other.

You can see which one your cluster lives in if looking at your "Clusters" list page in the Cloud Console, as there should be a column indicating the Dataproc region being used.